# MutationObserver doesn't work on cross-domain for Iframe src change detection

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain

I am coding an app for mobile that uses iframe to show our shopping site, iframe part is like that;

```
<div id="loadImg"><div></div><img src="images/loading2.gif"/></div>
<iframe id="frame-content" src="www.siteadress.com"/>
```

with above structure I would like to show a preloader image to customers while page is being loaded then hide the loader after iframe content is loaded fully (because connection speed issues)

I am trying to make a preloader image for an iframe and i need to catch the click event (src is changed - but i cannot use `onload()` because it only fires when the content is fully loaded) of iframe while one of the link is clicked in it.

To make it, i am trying to using MutationObserver method like that;

```
var mut_elem = document.querySelector('#frame-content');

//MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.attributeName == 'src') document.getElementById('loadImg').style.display='block';
  });
});
observer.observe(mut_elem, {attributes: true,attributeFilter:['src']});
```

but while above code works for same-domain, it doesn't work on cross-domain.
So i would like to learn that;

1. Can MutationObserver technique be used on cross-domain site? (if yes, how?)
2. If cross-domain is not possible with MutationObserver, Is there any way to make it possible (showing a loading image over iframe[cross-domain] and hide this image on main page when iframe content is loaded) with another way?

Thanks, right now..

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @Hanzo I'm sorry but I haven't too found a solution yet. And, I've gave up to use MutationObserver in my projects.